# How do I ssh/access my RDS database to alter tables with an ORM like sequelize

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am running sequelize and I want to run a node code on my RDS postgres database that will create and alter the tables. The back end is running on a lambda.

I have previously done this by opening an SSH tunnel into the database and running the code, but I can't figure out how to get the IP address of the RDS database in question.

Here's what i've done to get the IP address that hasn't worked ...

```
dig my-database.xxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

and

```
ping my-database.xxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

These both gave me the same IP address, but the tunnel command timed out.

```
ssh ubuntu@(IP Address from above) -L 8432:my-database.xxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
```

I tried digging around the RDS pages for the AWS console and looking through the VPC and subnet docs, but I don't really see anything.

Is there a better way to populate the tables? If not, how do I get the correct IP address and tunnel in to the database?

Answer (score 0):

This command: `ssh ubuntu@(IP Address from above)` is not going to work. You are trying to ssh into an RDS server, which doesn't allow ssh, and even if it did the user name would not be `ubuntu`. Also, if the RDS instance was on the public Internet such that you could SSH into it, then you could also just connect directly to the database without needing an ssh tunnel at all.

In the past you were almost certainly doing an `ssh` command into an EC2 instance. You will need a small EC2 instance running in the same VPC as the RDS instance in order to ssh tunnel into the RDS instance like that.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. Is there any way to create the tables without doing that?

Comment: Either change the RDS instance so it is public, and connect directly to it, or create an EC2 instance to ssh tunnel through.

Comment: It is publicly accessible, but I don't know how to access it in such a way that I can run sequelize commands.

I can run psql and it seems to connect to the empty database. I could use postgres to create the tables, but will this work with sequelize? I need some way to run node files with sequelize on the database.

Comment: If it's publicly available why are you jumping through all these hoops trying to ssh tunnel?  Just run your sequelize code locally with it configured to connect to the DNS name of the public database.

Comment: I didn't think that would work? OK. Maybe I am looking at this wrong. Thanks

Comment: When I tried running that, I got the error ..

SequelizeConnectionError: database "xxxxx" does not exist, so I figured that I needed a way to connect to the database before running sequelize

Comment: So run `psql` locally, with the public database DNS, and then type `create database <your-database-name-here>;` Then exit. Then run your Sequelize code.

Comment: Why do I need to create a database? The database exists on AWS, so what am I creating and how does it correlate with what is on the AWS server?

Comment: You're confusing the database server, which exists now on AWS, and the database schema inside the PostgreSQL software that still needs to be created. That is what the error Sequelize gave you is saying.

Comment: Yes. I am confused on those two things. If I run create database, what name am I using? How is that correlated with the database on AWS? Where is that name set or displayed within AWS?

Comment: I tried using "my-database" as the name, but that fails. If I use "mydatabase" that creates the table, but I have no way to telling sequelize what database name it is to be looking for. All I have is the URL?

Comment: You would use what ever name you want to give your database... That name is not set or displayed in AWS. How did you create the postgres database locally for testing your code? This question about ssh tunneling has devolved into a very long discussion about extremely basic postgres usage.

Comment: The postgres URL you give to sequelize should have the database name in it, like:

`postgres://dbuser:dbpassword@aws-rds-hostname:5432/db-name`

Comment: That is one way that I have tried, but I keep getting the response that the database doesn't exist. I tried using the url with the dbname in it as well as passing the database and link separately. Nothing works.

https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/getting-started/

I keep getting the response that the database doesn't exist

Comment: Yes you have to create the database with `db-name` first, using the `create database db-name` command in psql. Then give that URL to sequelize.